# Can't switch to nvidia GPU in linux mint 18

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia

I use linux mint 18 and i have nvidia GeForce 920m. From device manager i select nvidia-381 then rebooted but when running `lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2` command, nouveau still in use. What is the problem?

Here is `lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2` result:

[image]

Device manager:
[image]

Comment: I spent 48 hours mucking with nvidia drivers and mint, it's murder! I ended up using the nvidia-375 drivers successfully with `prime` and `bumblebee` which allow me to switch between my onboard GPU and the nvidia gpu either permanently or per-process. From what I see, first idea would be to try 375 since that's what works in my case (I have a GTX910m)

Comment: I tried it before and when rebooted, mint goes into fallback mode

Comment: It's done with `prime` and `bumblebee` and every thing is good. Thank you for hint